# ServletContext.TEMPDIR cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: jsf, servlets, compiler-errors

I'm working on migrating some JSF code from one project to another and suddenly in my new project the `ServletContext.TEMPDIR` value is failing.  I've run through most of my files but this is the only error and I'm not sure where to fix this.

Is not `tempdir` part of the servlet context?

I'm suing JSF and Spring btw.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That constant was [introduced](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#TEMPDIR) in Servlet 3.0, which is part of Java EE 6.

Your problem suggests that you're compiling your code against Servlet 2.5 or older, where this constant was [absent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#TEMPDIR).

Align out the compile/build with the target runtime and make sure that you don't have any servletcontainer-specific libraries in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Or, if you *actually* need to downgrade from Servlet 3.0 to Servlet 2.5, then replace that constant with the result of `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`:

```
File tempdir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
```

Again another alternative is to make use of [`File#createTempFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
File tempfile = File.createTempFile(timeString, ".xlsx");
```

Comment: Pom.xml looks like its using 2.5 - but changing it to 3.-something-alpha didn't help

Comment: The right Maven coordinate for Servlet 3.0 is [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1) (yes, 3.0.1 is exactly 3.0; the 3.0 coordinate doesn't exist in Maven due to a mistake). Or if you target a true Java EE 6 container (and thus not a barebones servletcontainer like Tomcat), then use Java EE 6 API instead, as [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/6.0). In any case, I updated the answer with two alternatives in case you can't (or aren't allowed to) upgrade.